How do I record the memory usage of a process in macOS Sonoma?
MacOS: Sonoma 14.6.1
I have a C++ program I have developed on my Mac and that I typically run from the command line. Depending on certain runtime parameters that I set, the program can run from ~10 minutes to ~24 hours (or more, I suppose, though I've never tried). I have been having a recent issue where the process running the algorithm for a medium-sized job mysteriously gets killed ("Killed: 9 <command line entry>") after about 3 hours. I suspect that there is a memory leak and that some component of the OS is killing memory-hog processes like this one.
To test this, what I would like to do is execute the program and launch a device to record the memory use of the relevant process. I do not want to manually monitor the memory usage through a device like Activity Monitor, top, htop, ctop, etc., until the process dies. I want to launch everything, forget about it, and then check the results in some log after, say, 6 hours when the process will have certainly been terminated.
Is it possible to do this logging?

EDIT (2024.10.28): To be clearer, I would like to record the time series of the memory usage at fixed intervals over the life of the job. It is this entire time series, and not just a summary, that I would like to view once the process has finished.

Perhaps a separate script to get the memory status at a given interval then write it to a file.

Instruments?

Run the command as an argument to time(1) — the system binary, not the shell built-in:
/usr/bin/time -l your-command-here

The output shows the peak memory allocation, among other things.
How to get the memory usage of a OS X/macOS process

Thank you for the suggestion, which I have now trialed. But what I was really after was capturing a time series at fixed intervals of the memory usage. So, for example, I would specify that I wanted a snapshot every 60 seconds and get 30 such readings for a job that ran 30 minutes.

Look at the footprint(1) man page and see whether that tool does what you want.

top can be used as a process monitor (with some caveats):
top -l 30 -pid 3911 -s 60

will sample the process with pid 3911 every 60 seconds, 30 times.
The output is rather verbose, you probably need to run it through grep to filter out the noise:
top -l 30 -pid 3911 -s 60 | grep '^3911'

The usual options of top (see man top) can be used to limit the columns gathered.
